# How to change first occurrence of word in a string

Tags: php, string, replace

How do I do to change the first occurrence of a word in a string?

Example:

```
$a = "Yo! **Hello** this is the first word of Hello in this sentence";
```

to

```
$b = "Yo! **Welcome** this is the first word of Hello in this sentence";
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works, although a bit inefficient:

```
$a = "Yo! **Hello** this is the first word of Hello in this sentence";
$a = preg_replace('/Hello/', 'Welcome', $a, 1);
```

The other popular answer:

```
$b = str_replace('Hello', 'Welcome', $a, 1);
```

does not work. The fourth argument of `str_replace` should be a variable, which is passed by reference and `str_replace` will set it to the *number of replacements made*.

A better solution would be to extract two sub-strings from the input string:

1. Sub-string before the first occurrence of `Hello`, call it `$s1`
2. Sub-string after the first occurrence of `Hello`, call it `$s2`

One can use the `strpos` to get the position.

Result is `$s1.'Welcome'.$s2`

Comment: Just saw your edit - I've implemented your second solution and posted it as an answer :)

Comment: *sees inefficient answer*... uses it in production code.  Why?  Much easier to understand than the second proposed solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use [substr](http://php.net/substr) twice with [strpos](http://php.net/strpos).

```
$a = "Yo! **Hello** this is the first word of Hello in this sentence";
$search = "Hello";
$replacement = "Welcome";
$b = substr( $a, 0, strpos( $a, $search)) . $replacement . substr( $a, strpos( $a, $search) + strlen( $search));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G4fKPF)

Answer (score 2):

This is the best for compactness and performances:

```
if(($offset=strpos($string,$replaced))!==false){
   $string=substr_replace($replaced,$replacer,$offset,strlen($replaced));
}
```

Replace only the first occurrence without the overload of the regular expressions

Comment: I tried to use this, example `$string = 'the quick brown fox eats the brown sugar.';`  `$replaced = 'brown';` `$replacer = 'yellow';` . The result I got : **brownyellow** . Result that I wanted : **the quick yellow fox eats the brown sugar.** I am sorry, did I miss something? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Build It:

```
function str_replace_first($search, $replace, $source) {

  $explode = explode( $search, $source );
  $shift = array_shift( $explode );
  $implode = implode( $search, $explode );
  return $shift.$replace.$implode;

}
```

Call it:

```
$msg = "Yo! **Hello** this is the first word of Hello in this sentence";
echo str_replace_first( 'Hello', 'Welcome', $msg );
```

Try It:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/399ec70333832423c79d36a42032124d5c296d27

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame str_replace can't do this with the limit argument, but here's an easy set of functions to throw in to your commons pile...

```
   function str_replace_first($search, $replace, $subject) {
        $pos = strpos($subject, $search);
        if ($pos !== false) 
            return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
        return $subject;
    }
    
    // -----
    
    function str_replace_last($search, $replace, $subject) {
        $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);
        if ($pos !== false) 
            return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
        return $subject;
    }
    
    // -----


    $test="ABCABCABC";
    echo "<LI>$test\n";
    echo "<LI>".str_replace_first("A", "", $test)."\n";
    echo "<LI>".str_replace_last("C", "", $test)."\n";
```

See https://onlinephp.io/c/69cab for a running example.

Note, regex replace is also possible - but it get's complicated when you're trying to work with some of the regex special characters... str_replace is easier.

Answer (score -1):

Use `str_replace('Hello','Welcome',$a,1);`

Comment: No: "If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements *performed*."