# php str_replace() duplicate words on search

Tags: php, str-replace

Trying to search and replace some content using `str_replace()`. It works fine if the `$find` is unique, but once if `$find` has duplicate words, the whole thing messed up.

e.g. The `style1` will be applying on both `$find[0] && $find[1]` since both are `Lorem Ipsum`, same goes for `dummy`.

How to deal with this situation?

```
$find = Array(
    [0] => Lorem Ipsum 
    [1] => Lorem Ipsum 
    [2] => typesetting 
    [3] => dummy 
    [4] => dummy 
);

$replace = Array(
    [0] => style1
    [1] => style2
    [2] => style3
    [3] => style4
    [4] => style5
);

$string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
           Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
           when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";

$result = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
echo $result;
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if there are duplicates?

Comment: Do you want the first occurrence of "Lorem Ipsum" to be replaced with "style1" and the second with "style2"?

Comment: @Nigel Ren Sorry didn't mention about the expected output. Should be something like find[0] replace with style[0], find[1] replace with style[1].

Comment: You need to replace only the first occurrence as you iterate over the `$find` and `$replace` arrays using something like the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272108/how-to-change-first-occurrence-of-word-in-a-string)

Comment: @Nick I tried what you suggested, but the `$string` is also iterating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an implementation of `str_replace_first` such as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match) and iterate over your `$find` and `$replace` arrays, replacing one occurrence of each value in the `$find` array only:

```
function str_replace_first($search, $replace, $subject) {
    if (($pos = strpos($subject, $search)) !== false) {
        return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }
    return $subject;
}

$result = $string;
foreach ($find as $key => $search) {
    $result = str_replace_first($search, $replace[$key], $result);
}
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
style1 is simply style4 text of the printing and style3 industry. 
style2 has been the industry's standard style5 text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/F8hZC)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying out RedYetiCo's ans

Comment: @Max no worries. Make sure you give an upvote to zombat's answer on the linked page.